# Не находит по артиклу в MySql

Tags: php, mysql, 1с

ДД,
делаю интеграцию с 1С,
Принимаю со стороны 1C файл выгрузки XML,
Делаю вывод данных с него проходясь по xml файлу, предварительно его подключив и создав новый xml объект:

```
foreach ($xml->ПакетПредложений->Предложения->Предложение as $value) {
  $price = $value->Цены->Цена->ЦенаЗаЕдиницу;
  $article = = $value->Артикул;
     //
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo 'Ошибка ('.mysqli_connect_errno().'-'.mysqli_connect_error().')';
            exit();
        }
        else{
           $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_product` WHERE `vendor_code` = $article"));
           //
           $product_id = $rows['product_id'];
           $rows2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_city_products` WHERE `product_id` = '.$product_id.' AND `city_id` = '6'"));
           $id = $rows2['id'];
           echo $article.' - Старая цена: '.$product_id.' ,  Новая цена: '.$price.'<br>';
        //    
        }
        //
}
```

До момента поиска товара в таблице, всё идёт нормально, артикул вроде корректный, товар в таблице имеется, но он не находит соответстввий.

Comment: Все выполняется через AJAX запрос, и я как понял он впринципе ничего не ищет, сделал проверку на подключение, ошибку не выдаёт но ничего и не ищет

Comment: `$article = = $value->Артикул;` уберите двойное `=`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov я опечатался у меня с одним =